# Caption over Images on Hover in Fluid Grid Layout - Dreamweaver CC

Tags: html

I'm working my project on Dreamweaver based on fluid grid layout for responsive sites. I want to reveal Caption on hovering the image. I tried lots of tutorials and tried answers in this forum as well but since I am working on Fluid Layout I can't set an exact image size ( in Px ) as in normal HTML. So that I can't overlay another layer for caption on top of the image layer properly.

So I decided to make sure the image and the text in the same layer and on hover action the text color will change from ( Transparent to White ) but I want to fade my image a little bit as well so I tried to reduce the opacity from ( 1 to 0.8 ) on hover action. But this made the text look faded as well and I don't want that to happen.

Can some tell me how to script Caption Over Images on Hover in Fluid Grid Layout Properly? Thanks!

P.S I can't add my CSS Code and Image links with the question, Please check out my comments!

Comment: This is my Script : http://jsfiddle.net/anishsrinivasan/5wLzgpjc/

Comment: I want Something like this : http://www.cssscript.com/demo/image-caption-hover-animations-with-css3-transitions-and-transforms/



My Current Setup : http://i.stack.imgur.com/UEkjE.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have done some example like **EXAMPLE 1** Unfortunately I couldn't work with your code.
Here is code:

```css
.wrapper {
  min-width: 1000px;
  margin: 5% auto;
}
.imgs {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  border:1px solid #cacaca;
  border-radius:5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.imgs .caption:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: #fff;
  height:305px;
  background: #000;
}
.caption {
  opacity: 0;
  color: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -304px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
}
h1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="imgs">
      <img src="http://www.gaykendds.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/bigstock-Red-apple-isolated-25800164-300x300.jpg">
      <div class="caption">
        <h1> Fruits </h1>
        <p>Some red Apple</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imgs">
      <img src="http://www.countryoven.com/ProductImages/big/Mixed-Fruit-Hamper.jpg">
      <div class="caption">
        <h1>  Fruits </h1>
        <p>Mixed Fruit Hamper</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imgs">
      <img src="http://disfrutaltd.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Peach-300x300.jpg">
      <div class="caption">
        <h1> Fruits </h1>
        <p>Some Peaches Fruits</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imgs">
      <img src="https://mauldinfamily1.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/lemon1.jpg">
      <div class="caption">
        <h1> Fruits </h1>
        <p>Some lemon Fruits</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imgs">
      <img src="http://kartdeliver.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/green-apple-300x300.jpg">
      <div class="caption">
        <h1> Fruits </h1>
        <p>Some green Apple</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imgs">
      <img src="http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=59589715">
      <div class="caption">
        <h1> Fruits </h1>
        <p>Some Orange Fruits</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imgs">
      <img src="http://my.xfinity.com/blogs/lifestyle/files/2012/10/tomato.jpg">
      <div class="caption">
        <h1> Vegetables </h1>
        <p>Some Tomato</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imgs">
      <img src="http://2.wlimg.com/product_images/bc-full/dir_67/1994770/almond-kernels-1536174.jpg">
      <div class="caption">
        <h1> Seeds </h1>
        <p>Some Almond</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imgs">
      <img src="http://beyouthful.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/1152191_avocado_on_white.jpg">
      <div class="caption">
        <h1> Vegetables </h1>
        <p>Some Avocado Fruits</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imgs">
      <img src="http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=45920356">
      <div class="caption">
        <h1> Fruits </h1>
        <p>Some Cherry Fruits</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Press *Fill page* to see it in full screen it's compatible with all browsers.

Let me know if you have any question.